# How to change the background color of setError() in Edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am displaying a error message using `setError()` to `EditText`. 
I want to change the background color of `setError()` message which is black by default. 
I searched almost everywhere but i couldn't get a correct solution though there are questions asked on this.

Answer (score 1):

you can change background color using java of setError() dynamically like this

EditText.setError("Your Error String");
EditText.setErrorColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

or
EditText.setError("Your Error String");
EditText.setErrorColor(Color.BLUE);

Comment: can u specified your andriod studio version and minimum platform which you used in your project?

Comment: I am using Android Studio 3.1.3. Java Language. minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28

Comment: This method works in updated studio 3.2.1 or you can try  changing minSDK version to 21

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your EditText inside TextInputLayout(it comes with some cool animations out of the box) then you'll be able to set any color for the EditText.

xml:

```
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/inputLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/selector_password_toggle"
                app:passwordToggleTint="@android:color/black"
                app:errorTextAppearance="@style/errorText"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/hintText">

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/passwordInput"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/registration_hint_password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

code in Kotlin:

```
        inputLayout.isErrorEnabled = true
        inputLayout.setErrorTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED))
        inputLayout.error = ERROR MESSAGE
```

Comment: use setBackgroundColor instead of setErrorTextColor.